# Removing cartridge from mixer tap - recessed nut

Tags: plumbing, kitchens

I am trying to remove a cartridge from a mixer tap, and faced with this recessed nut that I cannot get a wrench around. It's also an unusual shape (well, not hexagonal). There is no maker name on the tap. Any tips for removing the cartridge?

Best
Barry
[image: mixer tap cartridge]
[image: mixer tap cartridge]

Comment: Are you sure this is a nut?  Your photo is poorly focused but that looks like a spring clip holding this in place.  If you remove that I think you will be able to disassemble it.

Comment: See a photo, e.g. that on Amazon for a similar spring retention method. https://www.amazon.com/American-Standard-994053-0070A-Cartridge/dp/B000I7SGAG Better, look up your faucet assembly online.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to get a better picture (see above). I have removed the clip, but it didn't seem to make any difference. Should it maybe just pull out if I remove the clip? The clip must serve some purpose after all ....    I cannot find any manufacturer name on the tap, which makes it hard to look up.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that's a Carron faucet from UK. The design looks like you pull out the stem after the clip is removed. Similar to many other brand's designs like American Standard.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. It looks like this one https://www.tapmagician.co.uk/NSManufacturersShoppingSelect.aspx?MV02?Carron_Phoenix?Flora - with the "2 flats" cartridge but hard to be sure.

Comment: I agree. Looking at the cartridge, it should screw out counterclockwise. No need to remove the clip to get the cartridge out. Remove the clip to disassemble the cartridge afterwards for repair.